# Awaiting before an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have built a multi-step wizard that sometimes has step-dependant validation, i.e. checking that an address exists and then navigating away from the wizard if the values do not pass validation. However, not all steps require validation and, as such, it is not possible to return the validation function inside handleSubmit. I originally wrote the following:

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    const { handleValidation } = props
    let success = handleStepValidation
        ? await handleStepValidation(values)
        : true;
    if (success) {
        nextStep();
    }
}
```

However, the above didn't work because it wasn't waiting for the validation to finish before the if statement. I am somewhat new to async/await and I currently have the .then/.catch in each handleStepValidation function because the wizard is a generic wrapper for all steps. I have settled on the following code, but it seems somewhat ugly and I wanted any advice/help on how I could improve it:

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    const { handleValidation } = props
    if (handleValidation && (await handleValidation(values))) {
        nextStep();
    } else {
        nextStep();
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help in advance. Many thanks!

Comment: [The first piece of code works](https://jsbin.com/tapufagigu/1/edit?js,console). I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you add more details on how it doesn't work for you? A [mcve] is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
  const { handleValidation } = props;
  let success = true;

  // Only call the async if it's necessary
  if (handleValidation) {
    success = await handleStepValidation(values);
  }

  if (success) {
    nextStep();
  }
}
```

Comment: The first example is exactly the same but with ternary operator

Comment: Within a ternary, I think `await` can only be used in the first position.

Comment: @SimonLutterbie it doesn't matter where it's used - if you have an `await`, the engine will pause the function until the awaited expression completes.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example should work, but can be simplified like this.

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
  const { handleValidation } = props;
  if (!handleValidation || (await handleValidation(values))) {
    nextStep();
  }
}
```

If the await isn't waiting, we need to see the implementation of `handleValidation`.